# Show All data from Left table thought right table missing few

Tags: mysql, yii, left-join

I have 2 tables, In which one table has information about all application which I have and Other table has information about list of all user who has installed all the application.

If I fire following query It gives me proper result which I want, i.e All record in master table with corresponding values in settings table

You can find this result at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b39d/2

but If I Change user which got some missing records, I am getting wrong result, which left one result missing.

You can find the result at [enter link description here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b39d/1)

Please give good query to get all result from left side with some missing data on right side.

Comment: Your `WHERE` filter criteria are removing the desired records from the resultset; you should instead include such criteria in the `ON` clause of your outer join.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Here, tablea and table2 is left and right table.
     Col1 and col2 is common table both.
    and col3 is which column is not found in table1 missing entry,

    Ex:

    select t1.* from table1 t1
    left outer join table t2 on t1.colname1=t2colname2
    where t2.colname3!=null 

   your  Ex:

SELECT * 
FROM  `master_apps`  `master` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `tbl_settings`  `uas` ON   `uas`.`app_id` =  `master`.`id`  
WHERE
master.app_active =  "1"
AND uas.uid != NULL
```